# New Apple ID Sign In invalid grant issue

Tags: ios, oauth, signing, apple-id

So far I followed [this post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) and it helped me so much, however, I now get a "invalid_grant".
Following : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/errorresponse I understand that I have an issue either because of the authorization grant or refresh token is invalid.

In despite of my searches and tries (and retries), I am still stuck and I don't know where does it come from. I used the app given at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/adding_the_sign_in_with_apple_flow_to_your_app

Now that I get my token from the app above, I try to validate it from C# backend but I get a 400 response code `invalid_grant`.

The only difference I could notice from the post is that I don't have any `[Verify]` button (option) or `[Download]` button from the portal compared to the image below. I don't know if this is related but I am trying to provide as much details as I can:

[image]

---

Hopefully someone can help, thanks for any help :) feel free to ask for more details if required

Max

Comment: did you solve it? I am pretty much at exactly the same point you describe here.

Comment: Nop.. It doesn't come from my end so.. I am waiting.. I don't really know what to do tbh..

Comment: Hitting the same issue .. did you findout what the problem was ?

Comment: Nop.. but I saw the connect working on others apps so

Comment: 2 things you should note (caused me a headache): (1) The token is valid only for 5 minutes. (2) once you used it once - next time you will get invalid_grant. Also i didn't used redirect_uri at all and not verified anything.

Comment: How to manage `invalid_grant` issue for App sign-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same issue, I found the solution here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118135

as explained in the link, when you are using the code you got from the app, you should use app id instead of service id.

Answer (score 1):

Could you share how you try to create the JWT?
I ve tried a couple of stuff Im at this right know (which doesnt work either, Ill update if I find a real solution)

```
const string iss = "7#######G"; //  team ID 
            const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";
            const string sub = "com.######.weblogin"; // serviceid
            const string privateKey = "MIGTA#######"; // contents of .p8 file     

            var d = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5);

            var cngKey = CngKey.Import(
              Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey),
              CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);


            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();


            var securityKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(new ECDsaCng(cngKey) { KeySize = 256 , HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256});


            securityKey.KeyId = "G#######W";
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);

            return  handler.CreateEncodedJwt(iss, aud, new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("sub", sub) }),d, expires: d.AddMonths(3),d, signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
```

Headers look like that in the jwt, from what Ive gathered there might be the "typ" header which is not present in many implentation, perhaps I shoud get rid of it :

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "kid": "G#######W",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

body:

```
{
  "sub": "com.#####.weblogin",
  "nbf": 1583088895,
  "exp": 1591037695,
  "iat": 1583088895,
  "iss": "7######G",//teamid
  "aud": "https://appleid.apple.com"
}
```